# How to select all children except for the last child within a <div> by using JS querySelector?

Tags: javascript, children, queryselector

My section that contains testimonials + images need to horizontal scroll by using buttons. After integrating these buttons, one of the clicks lead to no testimonial item. My guess is the querySelector needs to select all children except for the final child, within the div class="SecondDiv_tablet" . How to fix this?

Html for the testimonials including images

```
<h2>Lees</h2> <h2 class="bold">Testimonials</h2>
                                <div class="SecondDiv_tablet"> 
                
                                    <div class="testimonials main"> 
                                        <img class="couple" id="Testimonial1" 
 src="./Assets/Testimonials_1_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1">
                                        <div class="testimonial1">
                                            <p class="testimonial">
                                                    We hoorden Strings 4 Weddings 
   spelen op de bruiloft van onze vrienden. Het optreden was zo gaaf, dat het ons 
   dagen is bijgebleven. Wij besloten ook klassieke muziek aan onze bruiloft toe te 
   voegen. Toen we zelf gingen trouwen hebben we direct contact gezocht met Strings 
   4 Weddings. De organisatie verliep erg prettig en de uitvoering was fantastisch. 
   Onze bruiloft zou nooit hetzelfde zijn geweest zonder jullie, erg bedankt!
                                            </p>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
          
                                    <div class="testimonials"> 
                                        <img class="couple" id="Testimonial2" 
   src="./Assets/Testimonials_2_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1"> 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="testimonials"> 
                                        <img class="couple" id="Testimonial3" 
   src="./Assets/Testimonials_3_mobile.png" alt="Testimonial 1"> 

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="navigation-buttons">
                                        <div class="previous nav-btn"></div>
                                        <div class="next nav-btn"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

                                </div>
```

script for selecting children within the div.SecondDiv_tablet class

```
    <script>

    const previous = document.querySelector('.previous');
    const next = document.querySelector('.next');
    const images = document.querySelector('.SecondDiv_tablet').children;
    const totalImages = images.length;
    let currentIndex = 0;

////
    // Event Listeners to previous and next buttons
    previous.addEventListener('click', () => {
      previousImage()
    })

    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nextImage();
    })
    
    
    // Function to go to next Image
    function nextImage(){

      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
        if(currentIndex == totalImages-1){
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        else{
            currentIndex++;
        }

      images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');
      
    }
    
    // Function to go to previous Image
    function previousImage(){

      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('main');
        if(currentIndex == 0){
            currentIndex = totalImages-1;
        }
        else{
            currentIndex--;
        }
    
      images[currentIndex].classList.add('main');

    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? `document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_tablet > *:not(:last-child)')`

Comment: It's way simpler to select the elements you want by a something they have in common like a common class: `document.querySelectorAll(".SecondDiv_tablet > .testimonials")` than this exclusion thing. This is way to fragile. Imagine you move something in your markup around because of some style changes and suddenly your JS falls apart and stops working.

Comment: Taking a second look at your markup, are you sure that you want *everything* except of the last element? What about the `.navigation-buttons`, are they also part of the images? Because they are not the last element, that's `.swiper-pagination`. And oops, suddenly your JS is broken.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the suggestions - I moved the .swiper-pagination outside the .SecondDiv_tablet div. Just in case. I tried the document.querySelectorAll('.SecondDiv_tablet > .testimonials') and it works!! Thanks a million

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @David784 - I tries the querySelectorAll () suggestion from Thomas and it already did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it an array and slice off the last element

```js
const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo')).slice(0, -1);

elems.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add('active'));
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;
}

.foo.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>  
  <div class="foo"></div>  
  <div class="foo"></div>  
</div>
```

Using a selector with [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [last child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.foo:not(:last-child)')

elems.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add('active'));
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;
}

.foo.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>  
  <div class="foo"></div>  
  <div class="foo"></div>  
</div>
```